# Flask is not releasing memory in Centos7

Tags: python, flask, memory-leaks, centos7, joblib

I have created a simple `flask` method that loads and unloads a dictionary object (containing `LogisticRegression` and `TfidfVectorizer` learned using `sklearn`) from the disk using `joblib`. Here is the function:

```
def load_unload_model():
    a_model_path = 'model.bin'
    print('Memory before loading model:', get_memory_usage())
    model_obj = joblib.load(a_model_path)
    print('Memory after loading model:', get_memory_usage())
    del model_obj
    gc.collect()
    print('Memory after unloading model:', get_memory_usage())
```

When I call this function iteratively using `Flask` method, the memory of process keeps increasing with each request. If I run the same function from the `Main`, memory before loading and after unloading model remains the same. This problem does not occur on Windows.

Here is the full Code:-

```
import os, gc, psutil, sys
from flask import Flask
import joblib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

app = Flask(__name__)
global_request_counter = 0


def get_memory_usage():
    a_process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    return str(round(a_process.memory_info().rss/(1000*1000))) + 'MB'

def load_unload_model():
    a_model_path = 'model.bin'
    a_model_path2 = 'model2.bin'
    print('Memory before loading model:', get_memory_usage())
    model_obj = joblib.load(a_model_path)
    model_obj2 = joblib.load(a_model_path2)
    print('Memory after loading model:', get_memory_usage())
    del model_obj
    del model_obj2
    gc.collect()
    print('Memory after unloading model:', get_memory_usage())


@app.route('/prediction_service/load_model', methods=['GET'])
def load_model_api():
    global global_request_counter
    print('Request:', global_request_counter+1, 'Started')
    load_unload_model()
    print('Request:', global_request_counter+1, 'Ended')
    print('-'*50)
    global_request_counter += 1
    return "Execution Successful"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_flask = 1

    if run_flask == 1:
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8060")
    else:
        for i in range(15):
            print('Iteration:', i+1, 'Started')
            load_unload_model()
            print('Iteration:', i+1, 'Completed')
            print('-'*50)
```

Here is the output on Centos7 using Flask:

**Request: 1 Started**
Memory before loading model: 71MB
Memory after loading model: 134MB
Memory after unloading model: 83MB
Request: 1 Ended

Request: 2 Started
Memory before loading model: 84MB
Memory after loading model: 152MB
Memory after unloading model: 87MB
Request: 2 Ended

Request: 3 Started
Memory before loading model: 85MB
Memory after loading model: 152MB
Memory after unloading model: 89MB
Request: 3 Ended

....
....
....

Request: 14 Started
Memory before loading model: 94MB
Memory after loading model: 157MB
Memory after unloading model: 102MB
Request: 14 Ended

Request: 15 Started
Memory before loading model: 102MB
Memory after loading model: 157MB
Memory after unloading model: 102MB
Request: 15 Ended